# Colorbar axis not formatting properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am having troubles with colorbar. It seems to output a whole bunch of overlapping ticks underneath the colorbar and I cannot work out why. I am also not sure how to get the colorbar ticks to be in scientific notation rather than how they are now. Here is my code

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatter
import matplotlib.colors as mc
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from   mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from plotbin.sauron_colormap import register_sauron_colormap    
register_sauron_colormap()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))    #This determines the size of the figure
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1, 1), axes_pad=0.0, share_all=True, \
            label_mode="L", cbar_location="right", cbar_mode="each", cbar_size='6%')

A = np.random.rand(58,58)
image = grid[0].imshow(np.rot90(A), cmap='sauron', interpolation=None, norm = LogNorm())

grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(image)
```

And the output

[image: is this]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Well, you specify ticks for the colorbar and it gives you ticks... Perhaps `yticks`? (is there something like that?)

Comment: I don't believe that is a thing unfortunately.

Comment: Where does `AxesGrid` come from?

Comment: And `np`/`xmin`/`image`... make a [example] please...

Comment: I also can't reproduce the issue, so make sure to update to the latest matplotlib version/specify which version of all relevant packages you're using.

Comment: Sorry about that! I have updated the original question with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: You have linked two plots, can you add better description to them? I have edited the question so they are visible, but it is kind of unclear which is your actual output

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug introduced by `LogNorm()` in conjunction with `AxesGrid` for unknown reasons. However, since you probably also have seen the deprecation warning:

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Since 3.2, mpl_toolkits's own colorbar
> implementation is deprecated; it will be removed two minor releases
> later.  Set the 'mpl_toolkits.legacy_colorbar' rcParam to False to use
> Matplotlib's default colorbar implementation and suppress this
> deprecation warning.   grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(image)

you may as well change your approach to plot the colorbar into the designated space.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from   mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))    #This determines the size of the figure
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1, 1), axes_pad=0.0, share_all=True, \
            label_mode="L", cbar_location="right", cbar_mode="each", cbar_size='6%')

np.random.seed(123)
A = np.random.rand(58,58)
image = grid[0].imshow(np.rot90(A), cmap='hot', interpolation=None, norm = LogNorm())

plt.colorbar(image, cax=grid.cbar_axes[0])

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]